# SQLSTATE[08006] [7] expected authentication request from server, but received _

Tags: postgresql, travis-ci

I configured my application (laravel 5.3) with travis-ci to work with postgresql database, but I got error in matrix build:

```
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] expected authentication request from server, but received _
```

I tried to change pgsql version to 9.4, with no success.

When SSL Mode is set to "prefer", build throws:

```
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] received invalid response to SSL negotiation: _
```

On mysql driver works fine and build passes.
Personally, I prefer postgresql rather than mysql, so I asking for help how to resolve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know travis-ci, but can you tell me what PostgreSQL client it uses to connect to the database? Do you want a SSL database connection? Is SSL configured on the PostgreSQL server?

Comment: I don't need SSL. Here is an example failed build with postgres 9.4: https://travis-ci.org/Macsch15/SimPas/jobs/155798918
Can't find any information about client https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#PostgreSQL

Comment: @MaciejSchmidt Did you find the solution? I'm having the same issue...

Comment: Nope. For now, I just switch to MySQL driver.

Answer (score 9):

Had the same error.
In laravel config for Postgresql by default it hase port 3306,
The correct one is 5432.
Or check your system